# R 64 running out of memory during SIMPROF

Tags: r, memory-management, cluster-analysis

I'm relatively new to R and am currently trying to run a SIMPROF analysis (clustsig package) on a small dataset of 1000 observations and 24 variables. After ~30 iterations I receive the following error:

> Error: cannot allocate vector of size 1.3 Mb.
>   In addition: There were 39 warnings (use warnings() to see them)

All the additional warnings relate to R reaching a total allocation of 8183Mb

The method I'm using to run the analysis is below.

```
Data <- read.csv(file.choose(), header=T, colClasses="numeric")
Matrix <- function(Data) vegan::vegdist(Data, method="gower")
SimprofOutput <- simprof(Data, num.expected=1000, num.simulated=999, method.cluster="average", method.distance=Matrix, alpha = 0.10, silent=FALSE, increment=100)
```

I'm wondering if anybody else has had trouble running the SIMPROF analysis or any ideas how to stop R running out of RAM. I'm running 64 bit Win7 Enterprise and using R 2.15.1 on a machine with 8gb RAM

Comment: Please make your example reproducible, right now it is hard for us to help you.

Comment: @Paul  

Does this help at all?  

The datafile I'm using is hosted [here on google drive](https://docs.google.com/open?id=0ByxraxSQssS2bi1hbUhkNXNVbDQ)  

And the libraries I'm using in R are, vegan and clustsig.  


Is there any other information that I can provide?

Comment: I did not run simprof, but I had a similar error with running other stuff. You need more RAM to make it work ( 16GB RAM will do) so you need to find a more powerful computer or the other thing that might improve it is you need to clean all your R environment and only leave you dataframe and required package and then try to run it. It frees up a bit of space. also disable wifi connection.